# Why can't I zoom my Unity2D Orthographic game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've watched several videos and read posts that indicate I should be able to zoom the camera view during my game by changing the Size parameter for the MainCamera (Unity 2D game, orthographic projection). Doing so zooms the Scene View in and out, but nothing I change anywhere in the Inspector changes the Game view.

Can anyone advise? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Is your game made entirely in canvas?

Comment: `Is your game made entirely in canvas?` It seems so, according to the hierarchy. In this case @RT2010, you have to adjust the settings of the `CanvasScaler` component attached to your `Canvas_Game` and `Canvas_Panel`

Answer (score 2):

The orthographic size defines the viewing volume of the camera and it will only zoom on the elements rendered by it. It looks like you are trying to zoom on a Canvas, but UI elements are rendered on top of the whole scene.

In order to zoom in and out you can either:

1. set the Canvas Render Mode to **World Space** and then place it in front of the camera
2. use a script that lets you zoom in on a canvas, have a look here: [Pinch zoom on UI](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1271122/pinch-zoom-on-ui.html)

   > ```c#
   >  public class PinchZoom : MonoBehaviour
   >  {
   >      public Canvas canvas; // The canvas
   >      public float zoomSpeed = 0.5f;        // The rate of change of the canvas scale factor
   >
   >      void Update()
   >      {
   >          // If there are two touches on the device...
   >          if (Input.touchCount == 2)
   >          {
   >              // Store both touches.
   >              Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
   >              Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);
   >
   >              // Find the position in the previous frame of each touch.
   >              Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
   >              Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;
   >
   >              // Find the magnitude of the vector (the distance) between the touches in each frame.
   >              float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchZeroPrevPos - touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
   >              float touchDeltaMag = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;
   >
   >              // Find the difference in the distances between each frame.
   >              float deltaMagnitudeDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;
   >
   >              // ... change the canvas size based on the change in distance between the touches.
   >              canvas.scaleFactor -= deltaMagnitudeDiff * zoomSpeed;
   >
   >              // Make sure the canvas size never drops below 0.1
   >              canvas.scaleFactor = Mathf.Max(canvas.scaleFactor, 0.1f);
   >          }
   >      }
   >  }
   > ```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: You guys ROCK! All I had to do was change the Canvas Render Mode and my pinch/zoom works like a champ.

This raises a question for me. This is my first Unity project. I thought we put UI elements on a Canvas, then the Camera rendered that for the display--like an artist painting on a canvas then using a camera to photograph. (You can't paint on thin air.) From this discussion, it seems I have that paradigm wrong. Can someone clarify (or point me to a place that will)?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: @LorenzoGoldoni please always if possible include the solution here instead of only referring to an external page. Thus, in case the external page decides to close or remove the content it is still available here ;)

Comment: @RT2010 there are a few different canvas render modes. Worldspace works as you described, but others are "attached" to the camera, do that they displaubthe same regardless of your camera zoom, position, rotation or fov. This is very useful when making an overlay for an FPS game for example.

Comment: @RT2010 as Louis said you would use a **Screen Space - Overlay** canvas whenever you want to draw elements that are non-diegetic, so out of the camera context. These kins of UI elements have the freedom to be completely removed from the game's fiction. Non-diegetic UIs can represent health and ammo or be a hotbar like in World of Warcraft. Non-Diegetic UIs are normally represented two-dimensionally. On the other hand, Diegetic UIs (**World Space**) exist in a game world instead of being overlaid onto the game, being part of the game's fiction.

Comment: If you want to read more have a look [here](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/4286/game_ui_discoveries_what_players_.php?print=1) and you should definitely check out Unity's rendering layers.
@derHugo Thank you for point it out, I just started giving back to the community!!

Comment: I spoke too soon. Zooming works fine on devices with my build aspect ratio (16:9). But when I run it on devices with different aspect ratios (including the Inspector), UI objects like Text and Buttons are no longer positioned correctly (they're off the edges of the screen). I'm guessing that's why I used Screen space-Camera view for my Canvases in the first place. (As I said, this is my first Unity project.) So...back to square one. How would I zoom a Canvas that's in Screen Space-Camera view (or else assure my UI elements stay positioned properly in World Space)?